# This Summation yields different results when a specific identity from Combinatorics is used.

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, summation-method

At first I had this summation :

$$    
\sum_{m=1}^{n} (m)\binom{n}{m}(3^m -2^m)
$$

After that I used the identity $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n}{r}\binom{n-1}{r-1}$

Which gave me the modified form of the summation:
$$n\sum_{m=2}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{m-1}(3^m-2^m)$$

But when I enter $n=2$ and $n=3$ , the two forms of the summation give different answers.

Comment: you changed your bounds of summation ($1$ to $n$ turned to $2$ to $n-1$)

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the quoted identity should lead you to rewrite the sum as $n\sum_{m=\color{blue}{1}}^\color{blue}{n}\binom{n-1}{m-1}(3^m-2^m)$. My guess is you thought $\binom{n-1}{0}=\binom{n-1}{n-1}=0$, which would allow you to delete two terms as in your limits, but in act $\binom{n-1}{0}=\binom{n-1}{n-1}=1$.

Comment: But if the limits of the sum remained unchanged on using the identity then we would have gotten $\sum_{m=0}^{n}m\binom{n}{m}=n\sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom{n-1}{m-1}$ Which would give us the invalid expression of $\binom{n-1}{-1}$

Comment: @AnikMukherjee Your original limit wasn't $m=0$, but in any case $\binom{a}{b}=0$ whenever $b<0$ (or $b>a$).

Comment: Yes , my original limit wasn't $m=0$ but how can we explain the face that sometimes we have to change the limits of summation and sometimes we keep it the same.

Comment: @AnikMukherjee We never change them. However, $\binom{n}{m}=\frac{n}{m}\binom{n-1}{m-1}$ is invalid if $m=0$, because then the right-hand side divides $0$ by $0$. When $a_k=b_k$ for $k\ge1$, $\sum_{k=0}^na_k=a_0+\sum_{k=1}^na_k=a_0+\sum_{k=1}^nb_k$.